# Is it possible to set a td with display flex to be full height, or have different CSS to achieve the same effect?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-tables

I have inherited a project where someone decided to set the `display` for a `td` to `flex`. One of the consequences of this is that when there are other `td`s in the row that span multiple lines, the `td` with `display: flex` does not stretch to the height of the other `td`s.

The correct way to fix this (I think) would be to remove the `display: flex` from the `td` and have it on an inner `div`, but I currently only have permissions to modify the CSS, so I'm wondering if there is any way to fix it with CSS only (while preserving the layout within the `td` as shown in the made-up code snippet below)?

EDIT: The desired layout is to have a left and right side within the `td`, the right side being a `span` that is a colored dot. The colored dot needs to always be on the right and top aligned even on a mobile device when the `td` is very narrow and the left side ends up wrapping.

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

span.right {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%
}

span.red {
  background-color: red;
}

span.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="flex"><span>Left </span><span class="right red">&nbsp;</span></td>
      <td>td with<br>multiple rows<br>blah blah blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="flex"><span>Left side longer </span><span class="right red">&nbsp;</span></td>
      <td>td with<br>multiple rows<br>blah blah blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="flex"><span>The right way to do it </span><span class="right green">&nbsp;</span></div>
      </td>
      <td>td with<br>multiple rows<br>blah blah blah</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The whole point of a `table` is to act like a table. Applying `flexbox` will negate this in many respects.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I'm just wondering if there's a workaround with CSS so I can provide a quick fix until I get permissions to modify the code that generates the table and do it properly.

Comment: I'd suggest you to write valid HTML before trying to apply any fix. 1) You opened `tbody` but never closed it. Also, your first 2 `td` tags are not wrapped in `tr`, however after them you included a `</tr>`.

Comment: Why do you need the flex display at all in there? What's wrong/unwanted if you simply remove it?

Comment: @juzraai - the missing `tr` and `tbody` are typos, I've added them. As per my post, I currently only have access to the CSS. I'm trying to determine if I can provide a CSS fix while I'm waiting for access to the HTML to do it properly.

Comment: @Johannes - If I remove the `display: flex` I lose the right alignment of the colored dot. I would love to remove it if I can find a different way to achieve the layout without changing the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the widths so that the right `<span>` takes up 2.3rem (`width: 1.15rem; margin-left: 1.15rem`) and the left `<span>` takes up the rest of the `<td>` width. Note the `em` are replaced by `rem` because they are not affected by casscading styles and inheritance:

```
span:first-of-type {
  width: calc(100% - 2.3rem);
}
```

In the example, all `<td>` and `<span>` are the same to demonstrate how the styles behave with different lengths of text in the left `<span>`. Tested it in moblie dimensions and it is always centered vertically and the dots always at the far right never shifting. The shape is always round as well due to changing `em` to `rem` and adding `height: 1.15rem;`. This is much better than `flexbox`.

```css
:root {
  font: 2ch/1 'Segoe UI';
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span:first-of-type {
  width: calc(100% - 2.3rem);
}

span.right {
  width: 1.15rem;
  height: 1.15rem;
  margin-left: 1.15rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

span.red {
  background-color: red;
}

span.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="flex"><span>Left </span><span class="right red">&nbsp;</span></td>
      <td>td with<br>multiple rows<br>blah blah blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="flex"><span>Left side longer </span><span class="right red">&nbsp;</span></td>
      <td>td with<br>multiple rows<br>blah blah blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="flex"><span>The right way to do it </span><span class="right green">&nbsp;</span>
      </td>
      <td>td with<br>multiple rows<br>blah blah blah</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use the `calc(100% - 2.3rem)` was the key, this got me where I needed without the HTML needing to be changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the real code contains instead of the red/green dot, but if it's an image or something similar, you can simply use `float: right` on it and remove the `display: flex` from the `td`:

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td.flex {
  /* removed */
}

span.right {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%
}

span.red {
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}

span.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="flex"><span>Left </span><span class="right red">&nbsp;</span></td>
      <td>td with<br>multiple rows<br>blah blah blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="flex"><span>Left side longer </span><span class="right red">&nbsp;</span></td>
      <td>td with<br>multiple rows<br>blah blah blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="flex"><span>The right way to do it </span><span class="right green">&nbsp;</span></div>
      </td>
      <td>td with<br>multiple rows<br>blah blah blah</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the first `td` is narrow for example on a mobile device - the color dot ends up lower than the text instead of directly to the right of it.

Comment: (The real code contains a `span` for the colored dot just like the example I made up)

Answer (score 0):

> so I'm wondering if there is any way to fix it with **CSS only**

Yes, use something like this to get the original/intended behaviour:

```css
td {
  display: table-cell !important;
}
```

---

> If I remove the `display: flex` I lose the right alignment of the colored dot

Add one more CSS rule to align that to the right, for example, using `float: right`

```css
span.right {
  float: right;
}
```

---

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

span.right {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%
}
span.red {
  background-color: red;
}
span.green {
  background-color: green;
}

td {
  display: table-cell !important;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody><td class="flex"><span>Left </span><span class="right red">&nbsp;</span></td><td>td with<br>multiple rows<br>blah blah blah</td></tr>
<tr><td class="flex"><span>Left side longer </span><span class="right red">&nbsp;</span></td><td>td with<br>multiple rows<br>blah blah blah</td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="flex"><span>The right way to do it </span><span class="right green">&nbsp;</span></div></td><td>td with<br>multiple rows<br>blah blah blah</td></tr>
</table>
```

---

Comment: This doesn't work when the first `td` is narrow for example on a mobile device - the color dot ends up lower than the text instead of directly to the right of it.